# How to prevent users from stopping a process in windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, windows-services

I have a WinForms/C# application that will be run across multiple computers (I can modify it), Now I want to disable the users from stopping it, The users will be using the computers remotely with a remote access software, The app will do some API calls and when some conditions are met it should stop the remote call, or turn off the machine, So the users shouldn't be able to stop this app.
I did some research and found some suggestions of using a windows service that will spawn the app once it's stopped, But then they can stop the service as well!

I'm not sure if I should secure the app itself or if there is an option in windows that can help me achieve what I'm after.

Comment: Don't make your users admins on the machine...?

Comment: Not allowing admin access is about as close as you're likely to get.  If this was possible, malware software would be abusing it left and right.